# AWS password policy for specific users

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, password-policy

I am fairly new to AWS and is wondering if there is a way to set password expiry for specific IAM accounts only. I know the default password policy has a feature where we can set to expire password in X number of days and I dont want that. I was hoping to see a much more granular way of setting password expiry for just specific users. I hope someone can share their thoughts.
Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

An IAM password policy is an account wide configuraiton which applies to all IAM users in an AWS account and this excludes the AWS account root user. This means you **cannot** apply an IAM password policy (in this case password expiry) to only specific IAM users within an AWS account.

See: [Setting an account password policy for IAM users - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_passwords_account-policy.html)

Answer (score -1):

Let me answer you with this analogy

`Your Aws account` - say this is `FATHER(root Owner)`, he is the sole responsibility of your account.

Now,`IAM Users` - They are his(FATHER's) `CHILDREN`,FATHER is very kind so whenever he allows a child to `enter(password permissions) exact permissions are applicable to all children`.**However, the roles and responsibility of child can be different (policies and permissions)**